# Redirect URL in Apache

Tags: apache-2.4

I would like to create a rewrite rule for the case if I open the URL "http://server.example.com/pagename", it will show the site of "http://server.example.com/index.php".

Unfortunately, I received an error in Apache that there was a redirect error and the request would never be finished. The URL seems to be in an endless loop: "http://server.example.com/pagenamepagenamepagenamepagename..."

Here is the Apache config file. Did I do something wrong?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Redirect / http://server.example.com/pagename
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
    ServerName server.example.com

    <Directory "/var/www/html/">
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you did unconditional redirect to http://server.domain.com/pagename

Try this config:

```
Redirect "/pagename" "http://server.domain.com/index.php"
```

or

```
Redirect "/pagename" "http://server.domain.com/"
```